# How to silence $(command)>/dev/null - within a function, not --silence the sh file

Tags: bash

I am calling a command from a script function. I would like it not to print to out, and only to a variable.
This prints to out:

```
MYVAR=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $1)
```

I tried to add `&>/dev/null`, but sure enough the variable is not set. Is there a middel step like; `$(command >MYVAR&>/dev/null)`

### Update

Just as I am waiting to accept @anubhava very good answer, I found this to explain [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually need is to suppress stderr since you're storing command output in a variable by using `2>/dev/null`. So use:

```
myvar=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} "$1" 2>/dev/null)
```

Also suggest you to avoid using all caps variable names to avoid chance of overriding an env var.